# Animation does not work in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am new to the Swift language and i am following a tutorial that is using a outdated swift language. The tutorial is about creating a animation with png files. So there are 6 png files that in total creates a animation. This is the link of the tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aCVyrJbrHQ". I have noticed a crucial difference in the old version of Swift and the new one. Here is where i get stuck.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let shooterNode = self.childNodeWithName("shooterNode")

    if(shooterNode != nil) {
        let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(shooterAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        shooterNode?.runAction(animation)
    }
```

New version: override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?

Old version: override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent

**Error**

As soon as i run the simulator and click on the object i get no response, no error just nothing. I checked if i made a typo with the object name but found nothing there.

This is the full code of the entire file in case you would ask for it

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ShooterScene: SKScene {

    var score = 0
    var enemyCount = 10
    var shooterAnimation = [SKTexture]()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.initShooterScene()
    }

    func initShooterScene(){
        let shooterAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "shooter")

        for index in 1...shooterAtlas.textureNames.count {
            let imgName = String(format: "shooter%01d", index)
            shooterAnimation += [shooterAtlas.textureNamed(imgName)]

        }
    }
        //Anime the shooter
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let shooterNode = self.childNodeWithName("shooterNode")

        if(shooterNode != nil) {
            let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(shooterAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.1)
            shooterNode?.runAction(animation)
        }
    }
}
```

GameSwift.scene

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let introLabel = childNodeWithName("introLabel")

        if(introLabel != nil) {
            let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.5)

            introLabel?.runAction(fadeOut, completion: {
                let doors = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1.5)
                let shooterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "ShooterScene")
                self.view?.presentScene(shooterScene!, transition: doors)

            })

        }
    }

     /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
          }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if every method have been executed as it should. Put some print statements in each method, and find out if everything is called correctly. That would be a start. Also put a print statement inside of `if(shooterNode != nil) {...}` block.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thanks for the respond, I added print on every function in the file and nothing appeared in the console. So i came to conclusion that there is something with the connection between my ShooterScene.sks and ShooterScene.swift file.

Comment: Where do  you present `ShooterScene` ? The actual creation of a new scene (and its transition) should look like this `if let nextScene = ShooterScene(fileNamed: "ShooterScene") {/* present scene here with optional transition*/}` So check that part.

Comment: @Whirlwind the Shooterscene.swift represents 6 Gif files from 1 to 6 that in total creates an animation. I have put all these files in a .atlas map as you can see i put it in the "func initShooterScene" and then i recall the node character name in ("func touchesBegan") called "shooterNode". I dont want a transition that i already have in my GameScene.swift file. I want my ShooterScene.swift play the gif files from 1 to 6 that is related to my object "shooterNode" in ShooterScene.sks

Comment: You are missing the point here ... I asked where do you present your ShooterScene. You have to present it, before you use it. According to that tutorial, presenting  of the `ShootingScene` scene (as well as transition) is done in `GameScene`'s touchesBegan. So, again, where do you present your `ShooterScene` ?

Comment: Look at at part [#33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15TcLdEbhrE&nohtml5=False) of that tutorial. He is making a transition to the `ShooterScene`. `SKView` have only one `scene` property. So it can present only one scene at the time. If you are currently seeing `GameScene`, you have to make a transition to `ShooterScene` to make it a current scene.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thank you for taking time and looking at the tutorial. Sorry for the misunderstanding. The thing is it does goes to the ShooterScene.sks ("I have uploaded the GameScene.swift just now") I am now stuck with the brains behind ShooterScene.sks aka ShooterScene.swift. At tutorial #36 in the comment section people have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be :

```
let shooterScene = ShooterScene(fileNamed: "ShooterScene")
```

rather than:

```
let shooterScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "ShooterScene")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Someone in the comment was very misleading about that line of code :(. But thanks bro!

Comment: @CecilBoye No problem :) It is a common error actually.